# Verifying a session is valid from Facebook Connect

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

In one instance I'm sending all of the Facebook session data through AJAX to our server.
The server needs to validate that the session is legit. I found this on stackoverflow: [Verifying a Facebook Connect session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357788/verifying-a-facebook-connect-session)

It says to take create a string like:

```
access_token=1290380d9e&expires=92d903&secret=e9cj9kd&session_key=s49i9i3f&uid=12345
```

And then to add your app secret key, so I'm assuming the string would look like:

```
access_token=1290380d9e&expires=92d903&secret=e9cj9kd&session_key=s49i9i3f&uid=12345&app_secrete=23132132
```

The `md5()` of this string should match the sig from the session data.
However it never does, so I'm just wondering if this is even a legit way of doing it, or if I'm way off the mark.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The technique is valid, but the description you referenced has some notable errors.

First, there should be no '&' characters in the string. I know it looks odd that way, but just leave them out, so the format is like NAME=VALNAME=VALNAME=VAL.

Second, don't try to include only a fixed list of parameters like the five listed. Instead, include all the available parameters except 'sig'. Otherwise your code will break whenever Facebook adds to or renames any of the parameters. And make sure to put them in alphabetical order.

Generate the string like that, and your md5 hashes should always match.

Comment: I tried a few examples based on your recommendations however I'm still not matching on the sig code.  See below (I anonimized the data for obvious reasons so md5s wont match)

Comment: `access_token=sdajdslkjald&expires=213123124214&secret=324324&session_key=asdasdsadda&uid=213213&app_secret=asdasd33242
md5 = 8158f7be460c5644ff4d669b5509c7c2`

`access_token=sdajdslkjaldexpires=213123124214secret=324324session_key=asdasdsaddauid=213213app_secret=asdasd33242
md5 = 0095b84394bbad230cd065f034948f9e`

Comment: `access_token=sdajdslkjald&app_secret=asdasd33242&expires=213123124214&secret=324324&session_key=asdasdsadda&uid=213213
md5 = c1fd895572193aceb4fd5cfa06164fe2`

`access_token=sdajdslkjaldapp_secret=asdasd33242expires=213123124214secret=324324session_key=asdasdsaddauid=213213
md5 = 58c4b9fb12835fe3981e3cf4373940a3`

`real sig =
84a896f966d87412034a2ef7a50dd41d`

Comment: When you add the app_secret to the end, just add the value and not the 'app_secret=' part. Sorry I didn't notice that in your original example. And make sure you are including all the parameters. On at least some occassions I see a 'base_domain' parameter as well, so that would also need to be included if present.